# PDF "Download Unsuccessful" Only on Android Phones

Tags: android, pdf

I know similar questions have been asked, but none of them were answered.
As the heading suggests, a PDF document is successfully retrieved on PC as well as iPhones from the URL (URL calls the controller of a C# Web API and the function returns a PDF in HttpWebResponse), but as soon as it comes to Android phones, it says "Download Unsuccessful", unless the link is opened in Opera.

The code below shows how the web response from the third party web service is converted to pdf and displayed:

```
bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(node.Value);
res.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
res.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");                                 
res.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=NatisDocument.PDF");
```

I have tried changing the mime type to application/octet-steam, it still does the same thing, and I have been stuck on the same issue for 2 working days.

Can anyone help? Or has experienced the same frustration?

Answer (score 2):

On an Android 4.4.2 device I have no problem with 'online' opening of PDF in Mozilla Firefox. 
However, the "Download Unsuccessful" error occurs in Google Chrome and the native Android browser only when retrieving PDF from secure URL (https://...). 
In such a case, do not tap on link, but press on link and choose 'Save link' in the context menu; then press 'Open'. See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62894/android-download-pdf-giving-download-unsuccessful

Answer (score -1):

From android lolipop, sdcard is not writable by default.
Try changing default download memory to internal and file download wont be unsuccessful anymore